# How to define all APIs in a common file/component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am comparatively new to ReactJS.I have an existing AngularJS app which deals with many APIs.How can I define all APIs in a common file/component in ReactJS and use it across the project?

I have tried the normal way by defining event listener within the component class of React.
Now I want to define all the APIs in a common place.

```
<RaisedButton label="Submit" primary={true} style={style} onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}/>
handleClick(event){
//API1
}
```

I want to define all project APIs in one file/component.And use it as:

```
handleClick(event){
//imported API1
}
```

I want something similar to factory in AngularJS.
How can we make similar structure in ReactJS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to make a request to all the APIs upon click of a button.

You can either use fetch or axios, both will allow you to make requests to a specific API endpoint.

Example of how to use fetch:
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Example of how to use axios:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

The handleClick function might look like this.
Upon click, it makes multiple requests to several API endpoints and retrieves
the results from said endpoints.

Does this help?

```
async handleClick(event){
//imported API1
const users = await axios.get('/api/users');

console.log(users.data); //logs out all users

const categories = await axios.get('/api/categories');
console.log(categories.data); //logs out all categories


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.I am already making calls through axios.I want something similar to factory in AngularJS.How can we define all the API calls in one place in React?